# Create a Util class that return an object containing start time and end time in UTC

Tags: javascript, typescript

This function when invoked will return an object containing start time and end time in UTC.

```
public getNowInUTC():Any{
  //GET LOCAL TIME START
  // GET LOCAL TIME END
  //CONVERT BOTH TO UTC
  //RETURN AS OBJECT

}
```

Expected Returned object

```
{
  startTime:"starttimestring",
  endTime:"endtimestring"
}
```

Here start local time is `starttime="T00:00:00.000Z"` and endtime `endtime="T23:59:99.999Z"`. Can anyone plz help me to write this function? I am a beginner in typescript.

Comment: I have doubt, actually, when you call the function will going to give same time for both start and end. Can you elaborate on it, please?

Comment: Yes, it will be going to return same time for start and end time.Start and end time is the ranger of time. @am2505

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It will return time in ISO format (T00:00:00.000Z).

```
function getNowInUTC(): {startTime: string, endTime: string} {
    let obj = {
        startTime: new Date().toISOString(),
        endTime: new Date().toISOString()
    }
    return obj;
}
console.log(getNowInUTC());
```

I hope this will help you.

**Edited**

To get in UTC Format (Tue, 16 Jun 2020 05:05:26 GMT). You can use this.

```
function getNowInUTC(): {startTime: string, endTime: string} {
    let obj = {
        startTime: new Date().toUTCString(),
        endTime: new Date().toUTCString()
    }
    return obj;
}
console.log(getNowInUTC());
```

Comment: I think your `toISOString()` should be `toUTCString()`

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, I have updated it. Thanks for point this thing.